# Deleted XIB files not being replaced

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm giving a complete overhaul to an iPhone app. As part of this I'm recreating a lot of the XIBs, by deleting the old one and starting again.

I've noticed that sometimes when I run the app (on either the simulator or a device), it attempts to load the old deleted XIB rather than the new one. This also results in an error "this class is not key value coding-compliant", as you would expect when some of the outlets have changed.

I can fix the problem by cleaning the project, and deleting the app from the simulator/device. Just cleaning the project doesn't seem sufficient. I'm concerned that when I release my app to the world, my users will experience this problem, with the only solution being to delete the app before upgrading.

The alternative would be to create the XIBs with a different name, but this is not ideal. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Dont worry about that, I am pretty sure your app is deleted and new version of the app is installed on your ios device.

Comment: I'm fairly certain Apple recently introduced partial upgrades through the App Store, ie. if the app is already installed it doesn't download everything. It's certainly that way for the OS, but I had a feeling it was for apps, too.

Comment: Usually, doing a 'Clean' and then a rebuild fixes this.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, just cleaning the project has not been sufficient. I need to delete the app from the device as well.

Comment: Have you checked the appdelegate to see if that is still present somehow?